# OpenVPN Client Issue

Tags: networking, openvpn, linux-networking

We have a call centre setup with an ubuntu server  as a DC box. We need to access our clients internal application . They have provided us openvpn keys. I am confused how can i have all 120 users access to that application without installing openvpn on each and every computer.

Please advice !!!!

Answer (score 2):

OpenVPN can be set up in LAN-to-LAN mode. Just establish the VPN connection on your Ubuntu server and then put in place the necessary routing bits to send traffic matching the remote subnet through the OpenVPN tunnel.